# android webview file download/php provides

Tags: php, android

Provides file downloads with PHP.
It works fine on the web, but it does not work properly in the app.
What is the reason why the header of the file is normally displayed but the file is not downloaded?

android webview download

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

headers

```
 header('Content-Type: ' . $this->mimetype);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->dl_filename . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    /* The three lines below basically make the
    download non-cacheable */
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header('Pragma: private');
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    // multipart-download and download resuming support
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && !$this->force_single){
        list($a, $range) = explode("=", $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        list($range) = explode(",", $range, 2);
        list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);

        $range = intval($range);

        if(!$range_end){
            $range_end = $size - 1;
        }else{
            $range_end = intval($range_end);
        }

        $new_length = $range_end - $range + 1;
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $new_length);
        header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $range . '-' . $range_end . '/' . $size);

        //set the offset range
        $this->mt_range = $range;
    }else{
        $new_length = $size;
        header("Content-Length: " . $size);
    }
```

download file

```
 if($file = fopen($filename, 'r')){
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && !$this->force_single){
            fseek($file, $this->mt_range);
        }

        //write the data out to the browser
        while(!feof($file) && !connection_aborted() && $bytes_send < $block_size){
            $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
            echo $buffer;
            flush();
            $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
        }

        fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: can you detail the implementation, what mime type do you use, how do you download? redirects? any errors?

Comment: The mimeTypes are listed in the headers.
The download will proceed without error.
However, only 50 bytes will be processed.
The headers are normally received from the app, but they do not seem to get the file.

Comment: I actually was referring to the mimetype and other information set to the download request, if you want to share